# Importing Caffe using sudo not working

Tags: 16.04, python, caffe

When I run the file with sudo it says it can't find it:

```
veli@veli:~/deepdream$ sudo python video-convert.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "video-convert.py", line 16, in <module>
    import caffe
ImportError: No module named caffe
```

When I run it without sudo, it does find it but unfortunately need permission for later in file:

```
veli@veli:~/deepdream$ python video-convert.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "video-convert.py", line 81, in <module>
    open('tmp.prototxt', 'w').write(str(model))
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'tmp.prototxt'
```

I've already ran `export PYTHONPATH=/home/veli/caffe/python:$PYTHONPATH` so I really don't know what else to do at this point.

Comment: how did you get caffe

Comment: I used git clone (from /BVLC/) , to build it, I did (in caffe dir): `mkdir build` -> `cd build` -> `sudo cmake ..` -> `sudo make all` -> `sudo make install` -> `sudo make runtest` -> `export PYTHONPATH=/home/veli/caffe/python`

Comment: Which user owns the directory where `tmp.prototxt` is to be written? Is that the same user running `video-convert.py`? The usual answer is to create a group with access to the directory, and make the user part of that group. `sudo` is not the answer.

Comment: Yes, the same user running `video-convert.py`. How would I create a group with access to the dir and join the group?

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED! (partially)

I ran:

```
cd
chgrp adm ./caffe
chmod g+rwx ./caffe
```

then:

```
sudo chgrp adm ./deepdream
sudo chmod g+rwx adm ./deepdream
```

(^it didn't allow me to run these non sudo for some reason^)

Then this now works:

```
cd deepdream
python video_convert.py
```

This manages to run it until I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "video-convert.py", line 85, in <module>
    channel_swap = (2,1,0)) # the reference model has channels in BGR order instead of RGB
  File "/home/veli/caffe/python/caffe/classifier.py", line 26, in __init__
    caffe.Net.__init__(self, model_file, caffe.TEST, weights=pretrained_file)
RuntimeError: Could not open file /home/veli/caffe/models/bvlc_googlenet/bvlc_googlenet.caffemodel
```

Answer (score 0):

(Can't comment on the other answer so I have to post this here)

To fix:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "video-convert.py", line 85, in <module>
    channel_swap = (2,1,0)) # the reference model has channels in BGR order instead of RGB
  File "/home/veli/caffe/python/caffe/classifier.py", line 26, in __init__
    caffe.Net.__init__(self, model_file, caffe.TEST, weights=pretrained_file)
RuntimeError: Could not open file /home/veli/caffe/models/bvlc_googlenet/bvlc_googlenet.caffemodel
```

Download `bvlc_googlenet.caffemodel` from https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/tree/master/models/bvlc_googlenet and put it in the directory it's missing form.